# Odoo 16 ir.actions.report qweb-pdf pass data via POST method

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

i have an issue with qweb-pdf report.
i always get "Request-URI Too Long" error when data are too big.
is there a way to switch to POST method instead of GET.

i dont know how to configure the report to pass data with POST instead of GET

im calling the report with

```
report = self.env.ref('XXXXXXXXX').report_action(self, data)
return report
```

i tried it with
report_action(self, data, config={'http_method': 'POST'})
as well, but i didnt work

thx for any answer

Comment: And there is no way to reduce the data? What kind of data is in that call?

Comment: hi, no, its a report to get all treatments of a month in some kind of a clinic. the same query can be downloaded as xlsx file. this works, but the pdf is needed as well. if there is a possibility to split the data in several pieces in one call, that would be a possibility. But i dont know how to split